# Which test do I use to compare if there is a significant difference in a binary outcome at two time points within the same group?

Tags: chi-squared-test, binary-data, biostatistics

I have a fixed group of 60 samples, with their serology status (adequate vs inadequate) at 2016 and 2018. Typically we would do this yearly, but I am interested to find out whether missing out a year (2017) on vaccination had made a difference in their serology status.

Which stat test would you use for this? As far as I understand, chi-square should only be applied for tests *between* groups.